# target pseudoclass with generated divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a page that uses the CSS :target selector to choose which tab of information to display. The tabs are created dynamically from AJAX-loaded data upon page load. A sample piece of code showing the functionality is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<style>
    #store div.tabs > div > a { background: #900;}
    #store div.tabs > div:target > a { background:#090;}
</style>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setStore() {
    var lastCat = "";
    for (var i=0;  i<storeList.length; i++) {
        if (storeList[i].category != lastCat) {
            lastCat = storeList[i].category;
            $("#display").append('<div id="'+lastCat+
                                    '"><a href="#'+lastCat+'">'+lastCat+
                '</a><div class="content"></div></div>');
        }
    }
}
function getStore() {
    function startWithStore(jcal) {
        storeList = JSON.parse(jcal);
        setStore();
    }
    $.ajax({
            url: 'getStore.php',
            type: "POST",
            success: startWithStore
    });
}
$(function() {
    getStore('display');
});
</script>

<div id='store'>
<div class="tabs" id='display'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page can be seen at http://royalbluetraders.com/testtarget.htm#Linen

When the page is initially loaded (say as "testtarget.htm#Linen") the Linen div is not selected, but clicking on any of the links works to select that div properly. It appears that the target property is not applied to the generated div.

So what is the best way (pure HTML/CSS or jQuery) to get the target div selected on the initial URL to be selected on the initial load?

Comment: You will get a better response if you isolate the issue with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: That seems a needlessly complex selector, wouldn't `div.tabs > div > a` be equivalent (*enough*) to `div.tabs > div:not(:target) > a`? Especially if you're styling the `:target`-ed `div`'s `a` element in the next rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.mylinks:first-child').addClass('makemelookgreen');
});
```

This all happens when the document is ready.  This shows a selector (you can use any selector you want) and then the second part is a jQuery .addClass() method, and you can add any class you want to that selected element.

Additionally, because the hash at the end of your url is not making the link 'active' as you would like it to, it could be because possibly elements don't actually receive the ':active' pseudo-class unless a click event is actually fired.  The hash at the end of the url simply tells the page where to go, I believe.

Comment: Using this basic idea, added an a.initial class selector with the div:target > a class. Then just after the tabs load, I pulled the target from window.location.href and added the lines:$("#"+target+" a").addClass("initial"); $("a").click(function(){$"a.initial").removeClass("initial");}); It works, but is really a kludge.